# Unable to push to remote Git repository, reading response from git-gui--askpass failed

Tags: windows, git

Since yesterday, I have big problems while trying to push to Github or Bitbucket (both fail on the same error). I am sure I'm putting in the correct credentials but I'm receiving this error after entering password:

```
Pushing to https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/PROJECT.git
error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass'
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org': Bad file descriptor
```

I haven't changed any options, it started to happen for, as far as I know, no reason

I tried to reinstall GIT-GUI, tried both GitHub and Bitbucket, tried to create new project. None worked.

Everything works on the second computer with same files.

Comment: corrupt file? try a check disk. See also these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345940/286994 // http://stackoverflow.com/q/14937496/286994 -- prefer SSH instead of HTTPS

Comment: Wow, chkdsk repaired it. Can you submit it as an answer?

Comment: that was a wild guess, I'm glad it helped hehe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corrupt file? try a check disk.

See also these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345940/286994
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/14937496/286994

Prefer SSH instead of HTTPS

Comment: Preferring SSH over HTTPS just fixed this issue for me. Thank you!